# The content part goes under the sidebar

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, sidebar

I have a sidebar menu, but I call it `position:fixed;` The content part does not see the sidebar as an obstacle and enters it. How can I fix this problem?

```css
aside{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1rem;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;}

aside .logo{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

aside .logo img{
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}

aside .logo h1{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 500;
}

aside .menu-one{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

aside .menu-one h4{
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

aside .menu-two{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

aside .menu-two h4{
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

aside .menu-one ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

aside .menu-one ul li{
    margin-left: 1rem;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

aside .menu-one ul li a{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    transition: 200ms all;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

aside .menu-two ul li a{
    transition: 200ms all;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

aside .menu-one ul li a:hover{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
}

aside .menu-two ul li a:hover{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
}

aside .menu-two ul li a i{
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    height: 30px;
}

aside .menu-one ul li a i{
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    height: 30px;
}

aside .menu-two ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
}

aside .menu-two ul li{
    margin-left: 1rem;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.cizgi{
    width: 80px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<aside>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Wikipedia-logo-transparent.png">
                <h1>WİKİPEDİA</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-one">
                <h4>Sayfalar</h4>
                <div class="cizgi"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-home"></i> Anasayfa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-id-card"></i> Hakkımızda</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-book-alt"></i> İçindekiler</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-stream"></i> Maddeler</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-two">
                <h4>Katılım</h4>
                <div class="cizgi"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-hands-helping"></i> Bağış</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-house-flood"></i> Köy Çeşmesi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-store-alt"></i> Wikimedia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-question-circle"></i> Yardım</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that your sidebar overlapping your content part, then please try to give padding-left to your content part

```
.content-part { padding-left:200px //equal to aside width}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm mad at myself for how I didn't think of Padding :/ thank you again